# Polymorphism in c#

Tags: c#, polymorphism

I have a problem with a class that is to spawn instances containing one out of about 30 objects of different types (I call it out_out_of_many_types_of_subcontract in the code snippet below).

```
class supercontract
{
    void supercontract (float date, one_out_of_many_types_of_subcontract subcontract)
    {
        stuff....
    }
}
```

Is there any way of declaring a semi-generic variable or must I (1) resort to polymorphism between constructors or (2) casting an object as a certain type with a block of (else)if clauses?

Cheers!

Comment: It's really unclear what you're asking. You should provide a more concrete example.

Comment: Just have all of those 30 objects implement an interface with methods for what this type needs to do with them.

Comment: Are you looking for an object factory or something?

Comment: what do you mean by "semi-generic"?

Comment: Ok, one_out_of_many_types_of_subcontract is a certain type, not just any. I have 30 so far, hence "semi-generic". I can re-cast this generic type (just using object, which will i guess will be true).

Comment: *"resort to polymorphism between constructors"* is polymorphism taboo or something?

Comment: No, but creating and maintaining 30 overloads could get pretty tedious

Comment: I second Servy's suggestion of making them implement a common interface, and then just have the method accept an object of that interface type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make them all implement a single interface.

```
interface IContract{}

class AContract: IContract {...}
```

Even if the interface is empty you can limit what types could be passed to your method.

Comment: Technically, a class implements an interface rather than inheriting from it.